# H1 and site content disappearing through banner as if they have a negative top margin

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm a bit of a newbie to programming so posting on here to find some help.

Had a quick question which I'm assuming is easily resolved through custom CSS.

If you check out this [post](http://www.beendorsed.com.au/business-reviews-and-trust) on my WP site you will see the content disappearing through the header.

Can someone please advise what piece of CSS has made this happen and what element I need to alter to set a regular margin?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that is causing you trouble is this one:

```
 h1.entry-title { /*spacing to position entry title dimensions &amp; font styles*/
     margin:-2em 0em 0.5em 1.5em;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size:2.8em;
     display:block;
     position:relative;
     color:#474747;
 }
```

It comes from a blog css file as "http://www.beendorsed.com.au/blog?sccss=1&ver=4.3.1".

**In that line, when you comment out the line "margin:-2em 0em 0.5em 1.5em;" (like this: "/* margin:-2em 0em 0.5em 1.5em; */"), all will go back to normal**.

---

To add that style to one set of pages only ("blog posts", for instance):

If you need that margin on one page, or one set of pages (like blog posts), add a class to it, like .post, and in the css file add it too, like this:

```
.post h1.entry-title { /*spacing to position entry title dimensions &amp; font styles*/
     margin:-2em 0em 0.5em 1.5em;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size:2.8em;
     display:block;
     position:relative;
     color:#474747;
}
```

When you add posts (instead of pages), you'll see that the articles are classed as ".post" (probably), just like the ones you are currently seeing are ".page". (I'm guessing the class name. Test it, see what the actual class name is, and use that). Here you have the line that states that class:

```
 <article id="post-21" class="post-21 **page** type-page status-publish hentry">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify `margin` value in you `.post` declaration.

```
.post {
    max-width: 640px;
    margin: 130px auto 0px auto;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Line **1804** in your style.css file

If you want to apply this just to on, specific page then do:

```
#post-104 .post { 
     margin-top: 130px; 
}
```

Comment: Hi Slick,

Just noticed your new response. I will try that when I am home. Thank you very much. 

Raz!

Comment: Another edit. If you want to apply this style just to one specific page, look at the unique ID. See my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the #primary definition to be

```
#primary {
    float: right;
    width: 66.6666%;
    margin-top: 100px
}
```

adding the `margin-top` there. You should get used to identifying the elements in a debug session in the browser to help you understand which element you are targeting.

Note that as I went through your CSS, I saw that you have some merge artifacts in the CSS, things like

```
>>>>>>> Another_Merge_test
```

which are not helping things for you.

Comment: Hi Shawn,

Thank you for the reply. I will try and fiddle with the #primary as per your suggestion - this is all a big learning curve. As such, not even sure what a merge artifact is? Google didn't help on this one.

Thanks again,

Comment: The lines with `>>>>>>>>` and `<<<<<<<<<<` are not valid CSS, but rather artifacts leftover when someone was doing a merge from source control. You should be able to delete that line without any mishap. If the answer works for you, please mark it as accepted. Good luck.